# toggle element on page load with a hash link not working

Tags: jquery, html, url, slidetoggle, fragment-identifier

I am new to javascript and using jQuery toggle effect on a button to open and close the following div. Here is my html:

```
<article id="book-section">
<h3>The new collection</h3>
<a class="btn" href="#book-list-one">Book list</a>
<div>
<ul>
   <li>Book one</li>
   <li>Book two</li>
   <li>Book three</li>
   <li>Book four</li>
</ul>
</div>
</article>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn").click(toggle);
function toggle() {
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle();
        return false;
    };

    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".btn").click();
}
});
```

It's supposed to be opening the div containing the book list when the user types in index.html#book-list-one but it doesn't. The toggle effect works just fine. I can't figure out what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated!!!
Thanks in advance!

Update: Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uxfb71s/)

Comment: Just added a JSfiddle. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have closing bracket incorrectly setup on function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn").click(toggle);

  function toggle() { 
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle();
    return false;
  }

  // and seems like the a tag in html snippet posted
  // doesn't have parent with the class name `.btn`,
  // $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".btn").click();
  // instead try access it directly
  $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").click();

});
```

Comment: Are you sure `window.location.hash` in your code return the correct hash from url? Cause when i harcoded the hashed url directly into a tag, it works correctly. See updated fiddle of yours here https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/pdz92ms7/